# How to change color when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of jQuery code which changes the elements of a couple of colors when the users scrolls down. But when the user scrolls back up the page, I want to switch to the original color. It doesn't work the way I expect...

Original Code that works

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() 
{
    var scrollTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop(),
    offset = jQuery('#masthead').height() - 55;
    if ( scrollTop < offset ) 
        jQuery(".float-manu").css({ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)" });
    else 
        jQuery(".float-manu").css({ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" });
})
```

Modified code that also works

```
})(window.jQuery);
jQuery(window).scroll(function() 
{
    var scrollTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop(),
    offset = jQuery('#masthead').height() - 55;
    if ( scrollTop < offset ) 
        jQuery(".float-manu").css({ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)" });
    else 
        jQuery(".float-manu").css({ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" });
        jQuery(".primary-menu a").css({ color: "white" });
})
```

Adding in additional css modifier to first if statement kills the script.

```
})(window.jQuery);

jQuery(window).scroll(function() 
{
    var scrollTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop(),
    offset = jQuery('#masthead').height() - 55;
    if ( scrollTop < offset ) 
        jQuery(".float-manu").css({ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)" });
        jQuery(".primary-menu a").css({ color: "black" });
    else 
        jQuery(".float-manu").css({ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" });
        jQuery(".primary-menu a").css({ color: "white" });
})
```

Comment: braces !!!! You need to wrap the content of your if statements or it will be out after the first line

Comment: You are missing the `{}` in if and else

Comment: Let me rain on the parade here... I'm often slightly amazed about the amount of upvotes for something that could arguably be a reason to close a question - a basic syntax error that holds little value for future reference. A good tip might be to just always put your code through a validator or look at the error console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are missing the brace in your `if` and `else`. Hence only the first line following the `if` and `else` gets executed. Instead add a brace like so:

```
 .....
 if ( scrollTop < offset ) {
      jQuery(".float-manu").css({ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)" });
      jQuery(".primary-menu a").css({ color: "black" });
 }
else {
     jQuery(".float-manu").css({ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" });
     jQuery(".primary-menu a").css({ color: "white" });
 }
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks, seems obvious but I wonder why they gave it to me without the brackets in the first place... thought it was odd.

Comment: @steve0nz because you don't need them if there is only one line after the `if(...)` and `else(...)`